# OleDbDataReader results DIRECTLY to an array

Tags: .net, vb.net

Currently I have a class that I created that will allow a user to input SQL code and then the class returns the results to an array in which they can further use. Most methods use a loop to transfer the data from the OleDbDataReader object to an array. This can be very slow when dealing with a large number of items.

Current method:

```
Dim SQLdr As OleDbDataReader  'SQL reader
Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand() 'The SQL Command
Dim firstline As Boolean
SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn 'Sets the Connection to use with the SQL Command
SQLCmd.CommandText = SQLStr 'Sets the SQL String
SQLdr = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader 'Gets Data
```

And then later..

```
While (SQLdr.Read)
  If firstline = True Then
    'fill headers
    Do Until j = SQLdr.FieldCount
      result(j, i) = SQLdr.GetName(j)
      j = j + 1
    Loop
    firstline = False
    j = 0
    i = 1
  End If

  j = 0
  Do Until j = SQLdr.FieldCount
    ReDim Preserve result(result.GetUpperBound(0), result.GetUpperBound(1) + 1)
    If display = True Then
      MsgBox(j & ":" & i & SQLdr(j).ToString)
    End If
    result(j, i) = SQLdr(j).ToString
    j = j + 1
  Loop

  i = i + 1
End While
```

I want to know if there is a more direct way out there to output the results into an array.. I am sorry but I do not have any idea where to start for this, if it is even possible, or if anyone has tried this before.

Comment: I just want to comment that I hope you're checking the SQL that your users are inputting to guard against SQL injection.

Comment: You could check if the DataTable.Load(IDataReader) method could be used. No array, but probably faster than manually looping

Answer (score 3):

Is this really VB.NET? However, you should not use `ReDim Preserve` to resize your array. Instead use a generic `List` and it's `Add` method. You should also use a custom class for your data, that increases readability, makes it more reusable and less error-prone. It's also faster when you don't use `Object` everywhere since it doesn't need to box/unbox.

Here's an example with a `List(Of User)` where `Ùser` is a custom class with two properties.

```
Dim users = New List(Of User)
Using con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    Using cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT UserID, UserName FROM dbo.User ORDER BY UserName", con)
        con.Open()
        Using rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
            While rdr.Read()
                Dim user = New User()
                user.UserID = rdr.GetInt32(0)
                user.UserName = rdr.GetString(1)
                users.Add(user)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Using
```

Here the simple class:

```
Class User
    Public Property UserID As Int32
    Public Property UserName As String
End Class
```

If you want to leave your code dynamic you could also use a `DataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable`/`DataSet`. That would simplify the code lot and would also be more efficient.

```
Dim table = New DataTable()
Using con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    Using da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT UserID, UserName FROM dbo.User ORDER BY UserName", con)
        da.Fill(table)
    End Using
End Using
```

Comment: It is definitely vb .net.... Also the point of my sql class is to remain dynamic. Wouldn't your method require to know the sql structure beforehand?  When the class is ran, the number of outputs can always vary which is why I used a loop.

Comment: Use a `DataAdapter` to fill a `DataTable` if you want dynamic fields. That'll simplify your code   lot. Edited my answer. My first approach is also looping a `DataReader` for the records.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to Steve for initially pointing me in the right direction and also thank you Tim.  I searched and found the solution here:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?381224-Filling-a-DataTable-using-a-DataReader

I used that method modified slightly so it includes headers and also to output it as an array as I had done previously.

For anyone in the future here is my finished code which runs a TON faster for loading results:

```
  load_sql(username_, password_, conn_string)

    If SQLConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        Dim myDataTable As New DataTable
        Try
            Using con As New Odbc.OdbcConnection(conn_string)
                ' Dim command As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(SQLConn, con)
                Dim SQLCmd As New OleDbCommand()
                SQLCmd.Connection = SQLConn 'Sets the Connection to use with the SQL Command
                SQLCmd.CommandText = SQLStr 'Sets the SQL String
                Using dr As OleDbDataReader = SQLCmd.ExecuteReader
                    myDataTable.Load(dr)
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            myDataTable = Nothing
        End Try


        Dim total_rows As Integer
        Dim total_columns As Integer
        total_rows = myDataTable.Rows.Count
        total_columns = myDataTable.Columns.Count
        Dim result(total_columns, total_rows) As String
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim j As Integer = 0
        Do Until j = total_columns 'add column headers first
            result(j, 0) = myDataTable.Columns(j).Caption
            j = j + 1
        Loop

        Do Until i = total_rows 'load data to array
            RaiseEvent progress(i, total_rows)
            j = 0
            Do Until j = total_columns
                result(j, i + 1) = myDataTable.Rows(i)(j)
                j = j + 1
            Loop

            i = i + 1
        Loop
        RaiseEvent progress(total_rows, total_rows)
        RaiseEvent query_finished(result, queryindex) 'display results

    End If
```